# Strange error in Android 6.0.1

Tags: android

```
 E/ItsOnOemAPI: Send local socket ADD_MEDIA_MAPPING failed
                                                                            java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
                                                                                at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:290)
                                                                                at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:130)
                                                                                at com.itsoninc.android.ItsOnOemApi.sendLocalSocket(ItsOnOemApi.java:265)
                                                                                at com.itsoninc.android.ItsOnOemApi.registerMediaMapping(ItsOnOemApi.java:245)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.media.MediaPlayer.registerMediaMapping(MediaPlayer.java:1273)
                                                                                at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1204)
                                                                                at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1164)
                                                                                at com.pakistantechhouse.quranmp3pro.activities.Start$MP1.doInBackground(Start.java:3138)
                                                                                at com.pakistantechhouse.quranmp3pro.activities.Start$MP1.doInBackground(Start.java:3111)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**I am getting the above error while playing a mp3 file from internet same code is working on later versions of android and also on 6.0 on most of the devices but on my test device(Samsung Galaxy note Edge SP-N915P) its giving me the above error and not playing the media files.**

Comment: you save the mp3 file localy on your device?, try to see if the path is correct and you got already a permission to read from local storage

Comment: @visionixvisionix No it just stream the file online and then play it as i mentioned its working on other devices but not on my test device, I also tried saving file on device which worked on other devices but same error on my test device

Comment: MediaPlayer.registerMediaMapping() doesn't even appear in any of the 6.0.x source code that I've looked at. (For example, https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r72/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java). I'm seeing this same stack on a Samsung Galaxy S5 with 6.0.1, attempting to stream mp4 video.

Comment: I changed the logic now its working.